# Dropdown for add to cart qty in Magento 2 only goes up to qty 4

Tags: magento2

I found the script below here to make a dropdown of the quantity on a product detail page. This works but it only gives a max of 4 while there is more (or less) in stock. How can I set it to the correct quantity/stock? Using Magento 2.2.5

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>               
            <select class="select" name="qty" id="qty" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" 
                   class="input-text qty" data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>">
                   <?php $i = 1 ; ?>
                    <?php 
                     while( $i <= $_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty()) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?>"><?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?></option>
                        <?php $i++; ?>
                     <?php } ?>
            </select>

        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: instead of drop-down add qty increment(+)/Decrements(-) button. Because if your product qty is 100+ then this drop down will not look good.

Comment: have you confirn above script is rendering this drop down ? like just delete this while loop and look this select removed or not?

Comment: Also if you var dump this $_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty()
it give you correct quantity which present in you indexer table ?

Answer (score 0):

For show product qty increment(+)/Decrements(-) button check below option:

1. https://magenticians.com/quantity-increment-decrement-magento-2/
2. https://inchoo.net/magento-2/add-qty-increment-buttons-to-product-page/